# Fortran not giving error on array assignment

Tags: arrays, dynamic, fortran, size, variable-assignment

I've got some test code here that is not acting as I would suspect. I'm using the gfortran compiler.

```
program test
implicit none

integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: a
integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: b

allocate(a(2))
allocate(b(4))

a = 1
b = 2
write(*,*) a
write(*,*) ' '
write(*,*) b
write(*,*) ' '
write(*,*) 'a size before', size(a)

a = b
a = 1

write(*,*) a
write(*,*) ' '
write(*,*) b
write(*,*) ' '
write(*,*) 'a size after', size(a) 
end program test
```

And I get the following output.

1           1

2           2           2           2

a size before           2

1           1           1           1

2           2           2           2

a size after           4

Why do I not get an error when assigning arrays of different dimensions?
Why is the size of a changed?

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour with `gfortran` version 4.8.4 (except that "a size after" is 8, not 4). I have tried to use `-fcheck=bounds`, but even that didn't work. Looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: Interesting, I'm compiling using gfortran test.f95 -o test.out. Someone should hire me to find bugs if this is the case, I always seem to run into them.

Comment: 8 is the right answer. Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature called [allocation on assignment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35810). When assigning an array to an allocatable array, this gets automatically resized. So after `a = b`, `a` is expected to have the size of `b`.

You can tell the compiler to warn about this via the `-Wrealloc-lhs` option.

See also this man entry:

> -frealloc-lhs
>
> An allocatable left-hand side of an intrinsic assignment is
>      automatically (re)allocated if it is either unallocated or has a
>      different shape. The option is enabled by default except when
>      `-std=f95` is given. See also `-Wrealloc-lhs`.

Also see the related blog entry [Doctor, it hurts when I do this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/03/31/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this) by Steve Lionel.

Comment: a(:) and -std=f95 don't seem to prevent the reallocation with gfortran.

Comment: Oh wait, it does keep the size of a as 2, just no warning, even with -Wrealloc-lhs

Comment: @KierenAnderson Does for me, though to get a runtime error it needs activated bounds checks: `-fbounds-check`. Without that, size of `a` remains 2. With bounds checks and `-std=f95` it fails.

Comment: @KierenAnderson with `-std=f95` it does not do a reallocation, so it does not warn about it. But it also does not check the bounds of the arrays, so just does the assignment (wrongly).

Comment: So why does @KierenAnderson get `a size after 4` then? Either he should get 2 (not resized) or 8 (resized), right?

Comment: @Ross, I would guess, his code does not match, what he ran, his output just shows 4 entries for `b`.

Comment: Ah, yes it should be a b of 4 not 8 for that output.

Comment: @KierenAnderson please correct that in the question